# Errors in Netty 4 http snoop example, with apache benchmark

Tags: netty

I'm trying to understand enough Netty to create a lightweight yet fully functional web server.  I started by copying the source code `examples/.../http/snoop`.  I run my server, and when I hit it in the browser it works fine, but it doesn't seem to work with the Apache benchmark tool. I try this to send it 10 requests:

```
$ ab -n 10 http://localhost:8080/foo
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 7 requests completed
```

In the handler, there is code like this:

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {
        HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) msg;
        ...
        buf.append("WELCOME TO THE WILD WILD WEB SERVER\r\n");
```

I added an integer count variable in there, just to get a sense of what is getting called, and after the AB runs, the counter indicates that the `buf.append(...` line has run 1200 times. That doesn't seem right. Any ideas? Is something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds related to the ab bug [1] of IPv6 hosts.

[1] http://simon.heimlicher.com/articles/2012/07/08/fix-apache-bench-ab-on-os-x-lion